# Is it possible to map what part of the internet will result in ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE when having network issues?

Tags: network, wifi, google-chrome

There is certainly an issue with my network provider, leading to the above nondescript Google Chrome Error on websites such as stackexchange.com, however, certain other websites such as google.com (and search results), as well as youtube.com (and videos) are working.

Is there any way that I can further diagnose what is happening?  Many answers online are extremely "hand wavy".  Yes I restarted my router, my computer, my browser, my ethernet service in the operating system.

Is there a better way to see what is happening to the HTTP requests?  Is there an issue with my DNS?  Why am I not getting an error 404?

I realize this may not be an Apple specific question, but many people are using Google Chrome on the Mac for browsing the web, and diagnosing connectivity issues seems important enough to make it relevant here.

Comment: Do u experience connectivity issues only while using Chrome? What happens with other browsers, especially when you try another one same time you get that error with Chrome? Which macOS and Chrome do u have installed? It might be best if you incorporate your answer to this comment also into your question.

Comment: Have you searched the web for that error in Chrome? I found links like https://browserhow.com/how-to-fix-err_address_unreachable-in-chrome/ which says the major ways to fix the ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE in Chrome are: Clear Chrome DNS Cache, Clear Browsing Data, and restart the router and device. It tells you how to do each of those things.

Comment: If you really believe the problem is with your internet provider's DNS servers, you can in Network Settings set your DNS resolver/server to be 1.1.1.1 or 9.9.9.9